# binding errors: "cannot assign requested address" and "permission denied"

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm currently working on a project that involves TCP/IP communication protocol. My goal is to send data from my computer to my raspberry pi 4 and vice-versa. The codes I wrote seems ok to me since there are no appearing errors when compiling and debugging my server and client files.However, when executing the server file on my raspberry I either get the bind error "Cannot assign requested address" or "permission denied"(that's when I write INADDR_ANY in the inet_addr() function). I know that these issues has to do with my IP but I don't see how to fix them.
Please can you help me with this !
Here are snippets of my server and client code:

server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>// enable write to be used
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

int my_socket, new_socket,c;
struct sockaddr_in server,client;
char* message;
std:: string  client_IP_Addr="192.168.0.102";
int bind_value;
    
//Create socket
my_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (my_socket == -1) 
{
  printf("Could not create socket");
}
//Geting client ip adress and port 

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
//inet_pton(AF_INET,client_IP_Addr.c_str(),&server.sin_addr);-->if value=1 => no error, otherwise yes there are errors
server.sin_port = htons(22); 
server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(client_IP_Addr.c_str());//--> error cannot assign requested address 
//server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);--> Get error permission denied


//Bind
bind_value=bind(my_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));//bind refuses to work although all values in it seems valid since there're no generated errors in the previous code lines
if( bind_value == -1)
{
  puts("bind failed");
  perror("bind error");
  return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

// Listen
listen(my_socket,1);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
new_socket = accept(my_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
if (new_socket<0) 
{
  perror("accept failed");
}
    
puts("Connection accepted");

//Reply to the client
message = (char*)"Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
while(true)
{
  int received_byte= recv(new_socket,message,sizeof(message),0);
  if(received_byte==-1)
  {
    printf("Error in recv()\n");
    break;
  }
  if(received_byte==0)
  {
    break;
  }
  write(new_socket , message , strlen(message)); // if write doesn't work try the send function
}
return 0;
}
```

client.c:

```
// ********************************************************
//  includes
// ********************************************************
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h> 
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // ********************************************************
    // Defining the variables
    // ********************************************************
    WSADATA win32_initialisation;
    int error, caracter_lenght;
    char message[65535];
    char server_reply[65535];
    SOCKET my_socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN destination_information;
    string server_IP_Addr = "192.168.0.105";
    cout<<"Hello, it's the client talking here\n";

    // ********************************************************
    // Winsock  Initialisation
    // ********************************************************
    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &win32_initialisation);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, can't initialise Winsock due to error :" << error << "! Quitting...\n" 
        return 1;
    }
        
    cout<<"WSAStartup  : OK"<<endl;

    // ********************************************************
    // Opening Socket
    // ********************************************************
    my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (my_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Sorry, can't create the socket due to error :" << error << "! Quitting...\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
        cout << "socket      : OK" << endl;
        

    // ********************************************************
    // Establishing session opening
    // ********************************************************
    memset(&destination_information, 0, sizeof(destination_information));
    destination_information.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, server_IP_Addr.c_str(), &destination_information.sin_addr);
    destination_information.sin_port = htons(22);

    error = connect(my_socket, (sockaddr*)&destination_information, sizeof(destination_information));
    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Sorry, couldn't open the TCP session due to error : " << error << "! Quitting..."<<endl;
        closesocket(my_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "connect  : OK"<<endl;

    // ********************************************************
    // Sending data
    // ********************************************************
   // strcpy(message, "Hi there Raspberrypi2906, How are you ?");
    strcpy_s(message,sizeof(message) ,"Hi there Raspberrypi2906, How are you ?");
    caracter_lenght = send(my_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
    if (caracter_lenght == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, couldn't send data due to error :" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "send  : OK" <<endl;
    }
    //
    // Receiving data from the server
    //
    if (recv(my_socket, server_reply, sizeof(server_reply), 0) < 0) 
    {
        cout<<"recv failed"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Reply received"<<endl;
    puts(server_reply);
    // ********************************************************
    // Closing the TCP session Corresponding to the connect() command
    // ********************************************************
    error = shutdown(my_socket, 2); // 2 means that socket is emiting and listening 
    if (error != 0)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, can't close the TCP session due to error :" << error << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "shutdown    : OK" << endl;
    }

    // ********************************************************
    // Closing the socket corresponding to the socket() command
    // ********************************************************
    error = closesocket(my_socket);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, can't release the socket due to error :" << error << WSAGetLastError() <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "closesocket : OK" << endl;
    }
        

    // ********************************************************
    // Promptly leaving the winsock opened with command WSAStartup
    // ********************************************************
    error = WSACleanup();
    if (error != 0)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, can't release winsock du to error : " << error << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }   
    else
    {
        cout << "WSACleanup  : OK" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: It is C++ not C

Comment: 1) Pick another port, 1024 or highert. Unless you're root you cannot bind to ports 1-1023, 2) If you're ssh-ing to your Pi, guess what port ssh uses, and is therefore unavailable to be bound by anyone else?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly @Sam Varshavchik. To keep on with your answer if I well understood, as SSH uses port 22 (wich is in the range of reserved ports as you mentioned in your previous message) it can't be bound to anyone else ?

Comment: Correct. Even if you're root.

Comment: I took into account what you said and made changes in my code (server side) and now I just have "cannot assign requested address" as a displayed error. I made some research and found that the bind() function only works with local addresses and so, as I wanted to bind my raspberry with my computer it's not possible since my computer can be considered as remote. However, I keep wondering if there isn't a way which I could use to do the work (bind them together). Thanks for your answer